# Value presence in the array pt.2

Tags: arrays, bash

Let's have an array:

```
echo $run
CEADAPST CENIPT CEDAMT CEODST +ASM CEREMAFT
```

Let's look if some values are present in the array or not (second and forth values are correct yet they are not found):

```
for dbname in CEREMAF CEREMAFT CEREMAFg +ASM; do if [[ " ${run[@]} " =~ " ${dbname} " ]]; then echo "you're golden!"; else echo "nope"; fi; done
nope
nope
nope
nope
```

Let's remove the space expansion, whole idea was to avoid similar words and go only for exact match:

```
for dbname in CEREMAF CEREMAFT CEREMAFg +ASM; do if [[ ${run[@]} =~ ${dbname} ]]; then echo "you're golden!"; else echo "nope"; fi; done
you're golden!
you're golden!
nope
nope
```

We do get some matches in the last case but the first match is a false correct (only similar because we removed the space expansion) and the fourth is still not found (probably because of plus sign). I clearly misunderstood the concept I found here on SO but I was not able to make it working and man, I tried... Why it doesn't work?

Comment: BASH array, dammit! Can't believe I put it only into a tag and not a name.

Comment: With `set -x` I found the space expansion in the first example expands WHOLE array, not every single value in it, that's why it doesn't work.

Comment: I tried `for dbname in CEREMAFT +ASM; do if [[ ${run[@]} == "${dbname}" ]]; then echo "you're golden!"; else echo "nope"; fi; done` as per help it should be literal matching but while both values are in the array, none is found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this function to handle that, it uses `namereferening` and two nested iteration to get you your desired result

```
run=( CEADAPST CENIPT CEDAMT CEODST +ASM CEREMAFT );

arrayIn() {
    local value=$1;
    local -n array=$2;

    local found=0;

    for val in "${array[@]}";do
        [[ "$val" != "$value" ]] && {
            found=0;
        } || {
            found=1;
            break;
        }
    done

    (( found == 0 )) && return 1;
    return 0;
}

for dbname in CEREMAF CEREMAFT CEREMAFg +ASM;do
    arrayIn $dbname run
    (( $? == 0 )) && { echo "yes"; } || echo "nope"
done
```

[namereferencing](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006)

Comment: Tested and works as expected, thanks. But to make own function is pretty far from simple oneliner which was supposed to go to .bash_profile and which worked well before that new db name with plus char appeared so I'm not gonna use it and instead somehow hardcode value in there even though I wanted to avoid that originally. I can't believe it is such problem to compare two arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
for dbname in (whatever) \\+ASM; do ...
                         ^^
```

Note the addition of double slashes.

From `help [[`:

> When the `=~' operator is used, **the string to the right of the operator is matched as a regular expression**.

So what does regex `+ASM` mean? Nope, it's malformed. Escape the plus sign and it'll work

Comment: I see, thanks. What if I feed values into `for` from another array? It seems I need to find a different operator than `=~`, that would solve the thing with exact matches too.

Comment: @Ren Use nested for loops and compare items one-by-one. Don't rely on `=~` if you don't use RegEx.